# Which substance(s) can solve gelatin (on film stock)?

Tags: solubility

I want to loosen the exposed layer on film stock which is made up of gelatin. Anything which would make gelatin dissolve that's not overly toxic? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hot water, about 100 C, should do the trick. Also, this article has some information on the properties of gelatin layers in photographic films.

[Properties and Stability of Gelatin Layers in Photographic Materials](http://albumen.conservation-us.org/library/c20/hendriks1.html)

Comment: Sorry about that  [Properties and Stability of Gelatin Layers in Photographic Materials] (http://albumen.conservation-us.org/library/c20/hendriks1.html)

Comment: thanks for that, interesting article. I tried boiling the film already but that hasn't caused any effect at all. Maybe I need more heat than boiling water in a cooking pot?

Comment: You might try heating the film in water for a longer period of time or , as you said, raising the temperature. This could be accomplished with a pressure cooker. Another idea is to try lowering the pH of the solution using a household acidic pH buffer, like vinegar (5% acetic acid).